# how to split array values in view page in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi CI developers I am new to CI framework so request you guys to help me in splitting array values in my view page. I am able to print the query values in my view page in this way, for which I wrote the following code:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($showdata); //I am getting o/p in this way
Array
(
   [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 205
                    [uid] => mh47
                    [profile_for] => self
                    [gender] => female 
               )

        )

    [count] => 1
    [pages] => 1
)
```

Now I want to split these array values and count values and pages values so request you to help me. I tried it this way but I am not getting any output:

```
    if (isset($data['showdata'])){
      foreach ($showdata->result() as $key) {
    <?php echo ($key->gender); echo $key['gender']; ?>
    <?php
      }
    }
    ?>
```

**below is my model page**

```
$data['showdata']   =   $this->searchresultss->login($per_page,$look,$age);

$this->load->view('searchresult',$data);
```

**below is my model page**

```
function login($per_page=3,$look,$age,$age_to,$age_from,$se_ct,$subsect,$coun_try, $sta_te, $ci_ty,$qualification)
{

$query="SELECT * FROM users";

$data=array();
$query=$this->db->query($query);
$data['results']=$query->result_array();
$data['count']=$query->num_rows();
$data['pages']=ceil($data['count']/3);

return $data;
```

when this works

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($showdata);
```

Why am I not able to echo the array value. I am in a lot of confusion, so guys please help me. 
I am new to CI framework so I am unable to sort out the problem.

Comment: no error output...not getting any o/p for for each value

Comment: enable error in config.php and see output erros. debug `$this->searchresultss->login` and see result return from function

Comment: You are printing out $showdata with print_r, but are iterating through the array that is returned from $showdata->result(). Try dumping that first and seeing if there is anything in there.

Comment: Iam unable to get you jamil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data['showdata']`only exists in the controller, in the view you should access it like this:

```
if (isset($showdata)){ //...
```

Your foreach should probably look like this:

```
foreach($showdata['results'] as $k => $v){
    echo $v['gender'];
}
```

Comment: @vicky You're welcome. If it helped you, please mark my answer as having solved your problem :-)

Comment: `$showdata['count']` and `$showdata['pages']`, respectively.

Comment: Weird, because your `print_r`at the top suggests otherwise. both count and pages are toplevel elements of the `$showdata` array...

Comment: thanks man solved it forgot to write echo..can explain where was i wrong

Comment: `$showdata`is an array that already contains all your data. In your foreach loop, you were treating it as an object. I'd suggest you read up a bit on arrays and/versus objects... :-)

Comment: Where was i wrong in splitting in array values Mudshark

Comment: Think of that `$showdata`array as one of those Russian dolls: you open one, inside is a smaller element ('results' in this case), which in term holds "smaller" elements in key/value pairs. If that makes sense...